# Change role names in gitlab from master to maintainer

Tags: gitlab

In some of our projects, we are moving away from 'master' branch to 'main' branch. I noticed in our project, we have a role called 'master', and I wanted to know how/if I can change it.

I see in the gitlab [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/permissions.html) that they no longer have a role called 'master', but it looks like it's equivalent is 'maintainer'.  However, from within our gitlab organization help pages (from clicking 'Help' under my avatar at the top left), the role is referred to as 'Master'.

Can I change the role within our project? Or does that have to be done at the organization level?

Answer (score 0):

[Permissions and roles](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/permissions.html) are statically defined in GitLab, as illustrated for instance by [commit a63bce1](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/commit/a63bce1a4b55bc6cbafb9dec12d33028521489e9), which did rename the `Master` role to `Maintainer`.

So unless you are modifying the sources from GitLab itself, or upgrading your on-premise GitLab to 13.x (since the change came during the 12.x releases serie), you would still see `master` instead of `maintainer`.